# Client Side Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, client-side

Any suggestions on a way i can paginate a client side block of text? I'm using a CMS so limited on the backend but essentially i would like a system where a user would create a big block of text and if that text was bigger than a certain size then it would paginate? Any examples of javascript or Jquery that does this? I've done some searches but they all seem to be table based.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

How about the [jQuery pagination](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/paginator/  in Yahoo! User Interface Library (YUI)